# django-rest-framework-datatables with Apache shows 414 URI too long error

Tags: python, django, apache, django-rest-framework, datatables

**Pre-requisites**

- OS - Centos 7
- Python 3.6.4
- Django 3.0 (or 3.1.1)
- Django Rest framework 3.11.1
- django-rest-framework-datatables 0.5.0
- Apache 2.4
- ORACLE 19.1

I have a simple Rest API - which fetches all data from a table in Oracle database. This Django Framework is hosted on Apache webserver. This data is fed into a datatable using the django-rest-framework-datatables.

- When I fetch data from the API using djangorest framework it works well.
- When I fetch data using the template with `?format=datatables` as the query parameter the URL is changed and it becomes a very long URL since my table consists of 50-60 columns.
- Thus throws a 414 error.

Did anybody else face this error ?

It works well with the django's inherent webserver but when used using Django fails.

Answer (score 1):

Django-rest-framework datatables also support POST requests which solves this particular problem of too long GET URIs, see:

https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-datatables-via-post-method

and:

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced such issue and reconfigured the code to shorten the URI.